# Struts2 not serving static resources after configuration.reload()

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, static-content

I am using Struts 2.3.15 and the `s:optionselecttransfer` tag is not working as the JavaScript does not load. I use:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<s:optiontransferselect ... />
```

which generates the following JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/optiontransferselect.js"></script>
```

My problem is caused because I call the Struts `configurationManager.reload()` method after loading some additional Struts2 XML config files that are stored in various plugins. Calling `reload()` kills the serving of static resources by Struts. My reload is done as follows:

```
ConfigurationManager configurationManager = dispatcher.getConfigurationManager();
StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider strutsXmlConfigurationProvider = 
        new StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider(strutsXMLLocation, false, getServletContext());
configurationManager.addContainerProvider(strutsXmlConfigurationProvider);
configurationManager.reload();
```

To solve this problem I have copied the files from `org.apache.struts2.static` to my server root so they are accessible and then used Roman C's code to prevent Struts serving static resources. This allows the `s:optionselecttransfer` tag's JavaScript to be found by the browser.

If anyone can hazard a guess as to why a `reload()` prevents the serving of static resources I would like to try to fix it. If there are no other ideas then I will accept Roman C's solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what modifications did you make?

Comment: The changes are to look in additional classloaders for struts classes. This was needed as the web-app uses Struts2 enabled plugins and Struts2 does not consider classloaders outside of `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`

Comment: Ah, interesting-that might be something worth bringing into the core framework.

Comment: That would certainly be useful for me. My mods are pretty hacky as I am grabbing the classloaders from my custom PluginManager singleton and so my code is of no use to the Struts core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s:head` tag should be placed under the head tag.

The constant used by `FilterDispatcher` by default serves static content from inside its jar.

```
struts.serve.static=true
```

If you want to access it from `context_path/struts` then turn it off by setting to `false`.

```
struts.serve.static=false
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about static serving, that might be useful. My issue was in fact caused by some customisations to the Struts2 `ClassLoaderUtil` class which are now fixed.